# How to show both count and proportion in the same plot for two periods in GGplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am a newbie and struggling with presenting frequency and proportion in the same plot. I was able to make a grid with two periods showing frequencies. I would like to show the proportion of each fruit (and dog) to be more informative. I manage to put a line, but it was pretty ugly... I tried with density and failed miserably.

In addition, I am unable to make gg1 (left plot)'s axis to be fixed on a scale of 10. (I solved this; UPDATE 2)

[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ6kL.png)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

policy <- data.frame("names" = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Dog"),
                    "period1" = c(1,7,2,2),
                    "period2" = c(4,10,4,2))

#create new column with "names" that breaks into new line. for nicer plot
names2 <- as.character(gsub(" ", "\n", policy$names))
policy$names <- names2

#manage font size in ggplot for names of bars, and in theme for title
gg.mid<-ggplot(policy,aes(x=1,y=names))+geom_text(aes(label=names2), size=4.5)+
 ggtitle("Policy Types")+
 ylab(NULL)+
 scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(1.0,1.0))+
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
       axis.title=element_blank(),
       panel.grid=element_blank(),
       axis.text.y=element_blank(),
       axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
       panel.background=element_blank(),
       axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
       axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA))

gg1 <- ggplot(data = policy, aes(x = names, y = period1)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Pre-2012") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
       axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
       axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
       axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
       axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
 scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip(ylim = c(10,0))

gg2 <- ggplot(data = policy, aes(x = names, y = period2))+
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Post-2012") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
       axis.title.x = element_blank(),
       axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
       axis.text.y = element_blank(),
       axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) + #this make Y axis (reverse) strats at 0 and stops at biggest value)
 coord_flip()



grid.arrange(gg1, gg.mid, gg2, ncol=3, widths=c(4/9,2.3/9,4/9))
```

Thanks in advance...

UPDATE

I tried adding ylim(0, 10) to gg1 (left plot), but got this out...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjl2c.png)

UPDATE 2

Adding expand = c(0, 0) into coord_flip() fix it.

```
gg1 <- ggplot(data = policy, aes(x = names, y = period1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Pre-2012") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip(ylim = c(10,0), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Comment: By "proprtion" do you mean "contribution of each element's total to the column total"?  So that for period1 it would be `period1/sum(period1)`?  As for your axis range issue, have you tried `xlim(0, 10)`? Or `coord_cartesian()`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. By proportion I mean e.i. % of apples in all fruits in given period. Regarding the limits, I tried ylim (it is flipped) but then the plot weirdly changes.

Comment: Ok.  In that case, `coord_flip(xlim(0, 10))` will probably give you what you want.  I'll write a proper answer when I can.

Comment: Solved the axis range issue (UPDATE 2). I still don't know how to visualize proportions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that appears to give you what you want:

```
gg1 <- ggplot(data = policy, aes(x = names, y = period1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Pre-2012") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_reverse(sec.axis=sec_axis(name="Proportion", trans=~./sum(policy$period1))) + 
  coord_flip(ylim = c(10,0))
```

Your `expand=c(0,0)` generates warnings and appears to be unnecessary.

[image: Bar plot with secondary axis showing proportions]

Comment: I'm sure there's a neater way of specifying the tansformation.  It's not my strong point.  If someone has a better suggestion, please feel free!